# How to compute E[W(t)^2] and E[W(t)^3], where W is a Weiner process?

Tags: calculus

How to compute E[W(t)^2] and E[W(t)^3], where W is a Weiner process?

I know E[W(t)^2] = t, but want to know the way how Ito's lemma is applied to calculate these expectations.

Comment: You just want to write down second and third moments of a normal random variable. Why do you want to apply Ito's formula?.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need Ito’s lemma

By definition $W(t) \sim N(0,t)$

So the moments of $W(t)$ are simply the moments  of a centred normal distribution with variance $t$